# 8051 UART, Receiving bytes serially

Tags: vb.net, serial-port, microcontroller, 8051

I have to send file byte-by-byte to serially connected AT89s52 from computer (VB.NET).
Every sended byte have some job to do in microcontroller what require some time.
Here is relevant part of my C code to receiving bytes:

```
SCON = 0x50;
TMOD = 0x20; // timer 1, mode 2, 8-bit reload
TH1  = 0xFD; // reload value for 9600 baud
TR1  = 1;
TI   = 1;

again:

        while(RI!=0)
        {
            P1=SBUF;          // show data on led's
            RI=0;
            receivedBytes++;
        }

        if (key1==0)
        {
            goto exitreceive; // break receiving
        }

        show_lcd_received_bytes(receivedBytes); 
        // here is one more loop 
        // with different duration for every byte
        goto again;
```

And here is VB.NET code for sending bytes:

```
    For a As Integer = 1 To 10
        For t As Integer = 0 To 255
            SerialPort1.Write(Chr(t))
        Next t
    Next a
```

Problem is that mC have some job to do after every received byte and VB.NET don't know for that and send bytes too fast so in mC finishes just a part of all bytes (about 10%).
I can incorporate "Sleep(20)" in VB loop ant then thing will work but I have many of wasted time because every byte need different time to process and that would be unacceptable slow communication.

Now, my question is if 8051 can set some busy status on UART which VB can read before sending to decide to send byte or not.
Or how otherwise to setup such communication as described?
I also try to receive bytes with serial interrupt on mC side with same results.

Hardware is surely OK because I can send data to computer well (as expected).

Comment: Why to lowering a baudrate when communication works properly?

Comment: When you lose 90% of the data because the micro-controller can't keep up then you don't usually say "communication works properly".

Comment: In this case baudrate is not a cause of data loosing but missing of communication control. Such, here can happen that for some operations in mC speed of 150 bps will be too high and for some 19k will be acceptable. Yes, communication works properly what can be visible through sending data from mC to computer.

Comment: Your computer won't have trouble keeping up, it has orders of magnitude more computing power than your uC.  And a UART with a FIFO.  And an excellent interrupt handler.  So seeing no data loss from uC to computer doesn't mean anything, it is the other way around that's the problem.

Comment: Hans, UART receive one byte good. Then mC have to do with this byte something what needs a time. In the same time computer sends next byte which can't be accepted, and then next, and next... You can't decrease baudrate enough if someone on controlled machine (my 8051) opens the door! Computer just need to know that this was happened to stop sending bytes. This is just my point of view.

Comment: If you don't want to lower the baudrate then an interrupt handler is paramount, you can't force the other side to stop sending quickly enough.  And you need a protocol.  A simple one is where you accept a command and send something back when you completed the command.  I think you already know this, the real question isn't clear.

Comment: Maybe is not because I am now become aware of problem. Find in the net now that UART in 8051 don't support any CTS/RTS options. They have to be done with port pins, connected physically to cable and programmed like so. That means - I have problem and have to think more on how to solve this generic disadvantage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is architectural.  Don't try to do processing on the received data in the interrupt that handles byte Rx.  Have your byte Rx interrupt only copy the received byte to a separate Rx data buffer, and have a background task that does the actual processing of the incoming data without blocking the Rx interrupt handler.  If you can't keep up due to overall throughput issue, then RTS/CTS flow control is the appropriate mechanism.  For example, when your Rx buffer gets 90% full, deassert the flow control signal to pause the transmit side.

Comment: Yes, I noted that. But how I already uses MAX232 for TX/RX I have two I/O pairs free for use for implementing RTS/CTS signals. I am new in this area so I thing maybe 8051 UART already have some mechanic for handshaking data flow. Now the things are a bit clearer. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Blast from the past, I remember using break out boxes to serial line tracers debugging this kind of stuff.

With serial communication, if you have all the pins/wires utililzed then there is flow control via the RTS (Ready To Send) and DTR (Data Terminal Ready) that are used to signal when it is OK to send more data.  Do you have control over that in the device you are coding via C?  IN VB.NET, there are events used to receive these signals, or they can be queried using properties on the SerialPort object.

Comment: Well tcarvin, I have control over that device but I don't know if it supports setting of RTS and DTR bits and how to set it. Actually, exact this was my original question to some experienced user of 8051.

Answer (score 1):

As @TJD mentions hardware flow control can be used to stop the PC from sending characters while the microcomputer is processing received bytes. In the past I have implemented hardware flow by using an available port line as an output. The output needs to be connected to an TTL to RS-232 driver(if you are currently using a RS-232 you may have and extra driver available). If you are using a USB virtual serial port or RS-422/485 you will need to implement software flow control. Typically a control-S is sent to tell the PC to stop sending and a control-Q to continue. In order to take full advantage of flow control you most likely will need to also implement a fully interrupt driven FIFO to receive/send characters.

If you would like additional information concerning hardware flow control, check out http://electronics.stackexchange.com.

Comment: Thanks for advice Jeff. On my board I have free resources for doing TTL/RS232 conversion, (luckily) exact for this two signals.

Answer (score 0):

A lot of these answers are suggesting hardware flow control, but you also have the option of enhancing your transmission to be more robust by using software flow control. Currently, your communication is strong, but if you start running a higher baud rate or a longer distance or even just have a noisy connection, characters could be received that are incorrect, or characters could be dropped.

You could add a simple two-byte ACK sequence upon completion of whatever action is set to happen. It could look something like this:

Host sends command byte: <0x00>
Device echoes command byte: <0x00>
Device executes whatever action is needed
Device sends ACK/NAK byte (based on result):

This would allow you to see on the host side if communication is breaking down. The echoed character may mismatch what was sent which would alert you to an issue. Additionally, if a character is not received by the host within some timeout, the host can try retransmitting. Finally, the ACK/NAK gives you the option of returning a status, but most importantly it will let the host know that you've completed the operation and that it can send another command.

This can be extended to include a checksum to give the device a way to verify that the command received was valid (A simple logical inverse sent alongside the command byte would be sufficient).

The advantage to this solution is that it does not require extra lines or UART support on either end for hardware flow control.